# Insert into UITableView at position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have `UITableView` with many contacts, when I add new contact, I want to inset into particular location (index) based on sorting logic(ascending or descending). Is there any method available to find it's position in `UITableView` based on `NSString` or any idea how to find my position without sorting the whole `UITableView`.

I am sorting initially like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
        sortedArray = [listData sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(sort_array:)];
    }
```

However, I don't want to do the same thing every time when I am inserting a new contact.

Comment: I've faced this problem a few times, I would add a tag to the cell, and base the tag off of the position in the array it's data is in.

Comment: if you have position to insert record then why are you sorting the array just insert the element at the index.

Comment: @CBredlow Its contacts, then I have to increase the tag for each user adding and need to decrease for deleting a user. It makes somewhat complicated. I think.

Comment: Well, when you add and delete a contact, you'd [tableView reloadData] and the tags would be updated

Comment: @VXtreme ya that is my question is there any method to find exactly the position based on my string?

Comment: @CBredlow Ya we can do like that problem is whenever I'm doing reloadData table view will update fully it will bring me to top of list. That I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: If you're maintaining the list in an array, it wouldn't be too hard to do a binary search to find the location and do the insert.  And after you update the table you can just scroll it to that item using scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:

Comment: @MikeM for that also I need position rit :)

Answer (score 1):

Look code Below i think you got answer :

```
sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: sort array after adding data in array. And use that array data in tableView for display data in caell

Comment: Jack then it will be like sorting again...? I don't want to update the  table for each insertion.